# Highcarts setData to specific series on click

Tags: highcharts

I have a very big data, so I wanted to load empty data but with legend names.

```
 dataArray.push({
      type: 'scatter',
      visible: false,
      name: item,
      data: null,
      marker: {radius: 4, symbol: 'circle'}
    })
```

Data is null, so it's empty. 
All I have is unselected legends.

So I want to fill empty data on legend click.

```
events: {
        legendItemClick: function (e) {    
          //someData is array
        this.chart.series[0].setData(someData);
        }
```

I want to setData to specific serie, depends on legend name..

Comment: Set the unique ID on each series and in legendItemClick use [get](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get) function to refer to series, where you call setData. The chart is availabel in this.chart object.

Comment: So it's just  this.chart.series[this.index].setData ?? I think it works like that.

Comment: in `legendItemClick` event, `this` refers to the series object. you can simply do `this.setData` and it would work. example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/du8htqca/)

Comment: Thanks.. It worked :)